# Cannot retrieve a url from $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I want to save a return url in the SESSION variable so that I can later return to from another page. I use the following code in page A:

```
$_SESSION['ReturnUrl']= $rawData['return_url'];
```

And I have used session_start() in the beginning of file.
Then, in page B, which comes up after a couple of redirects, I want to set this SESSION variable as action value for a form submit button, so that it can be used to return to the url saved in the SESSION variable. But, $_SESSION['ReturnUrl'] seems to be empty in page B. Here again, I have called session_start() in the beginning of the file. This is the code in page B that does not work:

```
$returnUrl=$_SESSION['ReturnUrl'];
  echo "<form action=$returnUrl method='POST'>";
  echo "<input class='center' id='returnstore' type='submit' value='Return to store'/>";
  echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Try wrapping your session start like this:
 if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
You may be overloading your session with a new one

Comment: try: `var_dump($_SESSION);`